# Emit log messages in real-time from executable while running in Tauri project

Tags: multithreading, events, rust, async-await, tauri

I'm working on a Tauri project where I have a command called run_executable that executes an external executable. I want to emit the log messages from the executable in real-time to the frontend using Tauri's event system. However, currently, the log messages are only emitted after the executable has finished running.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
 #[tauri::command(async)]
 pub async fn run_executable(window: Window) {
     let mut cmd = Command::new("../executables/pwdemo");
     cmd.stdout(Stdio::piped());

     let mut child = cmd.spawn().expect("Failed to execute command");
     let stdout = child.stdout.take().expect("Failed to capture stdout");
     let reader = BufReader::new(stdout);

     tokio::spawn(async move {
         let lines = reader.lines();
         for line in lines {
             window.emit("logMessage", Some(line.expect("Failed to read line")))
                   .expect("Failed to emit event");
         }
     });

     let _ = child.wait().expect("Failed to wait for child process");
 }
```

I want the log messages to be emitted in real-time as soon as they are available from the executable, rather than waiting for the executable to finish running.

I've used AI generated code, but I still can't achieve what I need. In this example I think that `reader.lines()` isn't getting updated when, the executable generates more output log messages.

Any suggestions or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!